# Unable to download url link with requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

The objective is to download a `tar.gz` from a `cvit.iiit.ac.in/projects/SceneTextUnderstanding/IIIT5K-Word_V3.0.tar.gz`

The file can be downloaded without any issue with `wget`.

```
!wget cvit.iiit.ac.in/projects/SceneTextUnderstanding/IIIT5K-Word_V3.0.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
```

However, the download the file using `requests`

```
import requests
url='cvit.iiit.ac.in/projects/SceneTextUnderstanding/IIIT5K-Word_V3.0.tar.gz'
r = requests.get(url)
```

Return an error

```
MissingSchema                             Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-11-fa35f2c0ddc0> in <module>()
      1 url='cvit.iiit.ac.in/projects/SceneTextUnderstanding/IIIT5K-Word_V3.0.tar.gz'
----> 2 r = requests.get(url)

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py in prepare_url(self, url, params)
    386             error = error.format(to_native_string(url, 'utf8'))
    387 
--> 388             raise MissingSchema(error)
    389 
    390         if not host:

MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'cvit.iiit.ac.in/projects/SceneTextUnderstanding/IIIT5K-Word_V3.0.tar.gz': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://cvit.iiit.ac.in/projects/SceneTextUnderstanding/IIIT5K-Word_V3.0.tar.gz?
```

May I know what is the issue?

Comment: There's literally everything you need to know in the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing http:// or https:// (the schema, as the error message says) in your `url` variable.

```
url = 'https://cvit.iiit.ac.in/projects/SceneTextUnderstanding/IIIT5K-Word_V3.0.tar.gz'
```

Answer (score -1):

You miss the http header

```
import requests
requests.get("http://cvit.iiit.ac.in/projects/SceneTextUnderstanding/IIIT5K-Word_V3.0.tar.gz")
```

This should also work

```
import wget
wget.download("http://cvit.iiit.ac.in/projects/SceneTextUnderstanding/IIIT5K-Word_V3.0.tar.gz", out="YOUR_PATH")
```

Comment: You can make this as a comment instead of an answer

Comment: mb, I will change it to comment. Just tried and yes wget works, added in the code for you

Comment: I know `wget` is working, but the OP clearly mentioned about `requests`

Comment: my bad, added now

Comment: `import wget` can't work if it's not installed (and you haven't mentioned that it's a separate module).